# Angular auth guard Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

im tryin to create an auth.guard.service but for some reason i get error `Can't resolve all parameters for AuthGuard: (?, [object Object]).`, here is the services.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  user = true;
  constructor(private auth: any, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.user) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

and here is the **app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './components/nav/nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { GalleryComponent } from './components/gallery/gallery.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ScrollToModule } from 'ng2-scroll-to';
import { NgxCarouselModule } from 'ngx-carousel';
import { AnimateOnScrollModule } from 'ng2-animate-on-scroll';

import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard.service';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    GalleryComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxCarouselModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ScrollToModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    AnimateOnScrollModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

i dont know where could be error is, the services that im importin on the `auth.guard.services` is commented because i not using it yet, just in case, for some reason i can resolve all the parameters if somebody have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is a run-time error related to Angular Dependency Injection. It can't determine how to create the dependency represented by the first constructor parameter because its type is `any`. You can change the type from `any` to some type that is provided or use @Inject on a type or token that is provided. Angular DI shouldn't have a problem with the second parameter (`Router`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "any" in your constructor.  constructor(private auth: **any**, private router: Router).  Change it to your service like authService.